# rotate a Ogre Manual Object between two Ogre vectors

Tags: c++, vector, rotation, geometry, ogre

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sO0I.png)I am working on a rviz plugin project in which I need to move a ogre cube mesh structure between two coordinates.

Here is the code what I have done for this

```
Ogre::Vector3 src (1,2,3);
Ogre::Vector3 destination(4,5,6);
//manual object
static int count=0;
const std::string& filename="cube.mesh";
Ogre::MeshPtr cube= rviz::loadMeshFromResource(filename);    
std::stringstream str;
str << "cube" << count++;
Ogre::Entity *entity = scene_manager_->createEntity(str.str(),cube);
Ogre::SceneNode* parent_node = scene_manager_->getRootSceneNode();
parent_node ->attachObject(entity);
parent_node ->setPosition((src+destination)/2);   //by doing this the cube passes through mid point
Ogre::Radian angle = src.angleBetween(destination);

//here is some error, 
Ogre::Quaternion angle_x((angle), Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_X);
Ogre::Quaternion angle_y((angle), Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_Y);
Ogre::Quaternion angle_z((angle), Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_Z);
parent_node ->rotate(angle_x*angle_y*angle_z);
```

However it's not getting aligned between two vectors . Please help.

Comment: What are src and destination - positions? What does mean "angle" between two positions?

Comment: src and destination are two coordinates which I have received from a ros bag file. 
By Angle I mean the orientation of the cube structure. It should point from src to destination side or destination to src side but it side be aligned in that orientation.

Answer (score 0):

To get direction from src point to destination one, you have to subtract these positions, getting vector.

As far as I understand (know nothing about Ogre), `src.angleBetween(destination);` gives angular difference between direction from origin to destrination and direction from origin to src. Note it is **not** angle between "origin to src" and "src to destination" directions.

Moreover, `Ogre::Radian angle` is scalar value, an angle in radians, you cannot get rotation matrix from this value (matrix needed to align vectors)

Comment: It worked only for one coordinate. 
Let say I have three coordinates src(0,0,0), destination1(200,10,3) and destination2(200,10,14).
I am calculating the difference and using Ogre::Vector3 getRotationTo I am able to align object between src and destination1 ,on rotating it around UNIT_X axis. but I am not able to do so for src and destination2, may be something is related to UNIT_X axis orientation. But I am not able to figure it out. I could have posted the code but I lost connection to VM,

Comment: I added some thoughts. Perhaps it  is worth to make a sketch for 2D case for better explanation of your problem.